# Composer failing when I use Route::controller() in my routes.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on migrating an existing Laravel 3 application over to Laravel 4.1, and routes are kicking my butt right now. Here is the problem I'm having- in the old application we made frequent use of Route::controller() in the routes file.  When I bring those entries over to the new application they seem to work, but they cause composer to get nasty.

For example I have this route:

```
Route::controller('templates', 'AdminTemplatesController');
```

Which is working as a route.  But when I run composer update I get this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ReflectionException","message":"Class AdminTemplatesController does not exist","file":"\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerInspector.php","line":28}}
```

I've tried stripping down and using Artisan to create an entirely new controller- same test, same fail.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does that controller exists?

Comment: It does exist-- and even more odd (to me at least) it's actually echoing the contents of that entire file to the command line before the error I've shown above.  Twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to do it in steps:

1) Disable all of your routes

2) Execute `composer update` and make the process pass, you don't need your routes to do that

3) Reenable the controller route and fix the issue Laravel is having by not finding it, which could be:

- Controllers folder not being loaded in composer.json
- Namespace not being loaded  in composer.json

In all of those cases, you have to be sure that you have your controllers in any of the files of the folder:

```
vendor/composer
```

For example, if you have the controllers folder in the autoload->classmap of composer.json, the file will be:

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

Remember that every time you change composer.json, you have to

```
composer dumpautoload
```

So it recreates those files.

EDIT:

About your comment, I had similar problem once when my file was printed in command line, was happening because I had:

```
<?
```

instead of

```
<?php
```

This makes difference for Laravel.

Comment: I've tried commenting all controller routes in the file and I am able to get composer to update.  Adding them back in gives me the same result.  If I route to the controller using a Route::get, Route::post, Route::match etc. I don't trigger the composer failure.  Also, the routes actually work in the browser, it's only composer that's failing.

Comment: Not sure if it's your case, but I just edited to try to help with the "echoing the contents" problem.

Comment: Wow, it never even occurred to me to check that.  Fixed both the echo problem and the failing composer problem.

Comment: I would never forget something that odd. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4 you use "Route::resource()". So your example would be Route::resource('templates', 'AdminTemplatesController');

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: According to the docs there are resource controllers, and there are restful controllers.  So they show this as an example of a RESTful controller route:  Route::controller('users', 'UserController');